# Who is the Inventor of Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Purely out of curiosity, who is the inventor of the Windows PowerShell ? As I have seen it on every Windows machine.
So could someone please give me an insight on who the inventor of the Windows PowerShell is?

**EDIT**
I have read the help center and do realize that this is sort-of off topic.This topic may remain locked if you choose so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its **Jeffrey Snover**, Inventor and Architect of **Windows PowerShell** and currently the Lead Architect for **Windows Server 2012**.

Comment: the name is Jeffrey, not Jeffery. i just updated that

Comment: his StackOverflow profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/69339/jeffrey-snover-msft
Microsoft profile: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Profile/jeffrey%20snover%20windows%20server

Comment: and god bless him! powershell por vida!

Answer (score 8):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) says "Designed by: Jeffrey Snover, Bruce Payette, James Truher"

Comment: Thank you for this information aswel but unfortunately I cannot "check" your answer as correct due to the following that Pradeep Kumar replied first.

Comment: np, keep hacking :)

Comment: OK, then I will do it in Petzl11' s stead.